# How can I delete selected item from spinner on click button?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, save, spinner

I am working on an android app and I have those code in c# in Xamarin, Visual stuio:

```
const string KEY_FOR_TRY = "TRY";

ArrayAdapter<string> _spinnerAdapter;
List<string> items;

protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

    string user;
    ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (this);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
    var savedItems = prefs.GetStringSet (KEY_FOR_TRY, new List<string> ());
_spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);

 spinner.Adapter = _spinnerAdapter;

    items = new List<string> (savedItems) {"1", "2", "3"};

    Button button4 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button4);
    Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.spinner1);
    EditText input = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.input);

    button4.Click += delegate
            {
                user = input.Text;
                items.Add (user);
                editor.PutStringSet (KEY_FOR_TRY, items);
                editor.Apply ();
                _spinnerAdapter.Insert (user, 0);
                _spinnerAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();
            };
    user = items.FirstOrDefault ();

    _spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);

    spinner.Adapter = _spinnerAdapter;
}

Button button5 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button5);
        button5.Click += delegate
        {
            items.Remove(spinner.SelectedItem.ToString());
            editor.Remove(spinner.SelectedItem.ToString());
            editor.Apply();
            _spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);
            spinner.Adapter = _spinnerAdapter;
        };
        user = items.FirstOrDefault();
        spinner.Adapter = _spinnerAdapter;
```

I want to have a `button5` which delete the user selected item from `spinner` and also from the `SharedPreference prefs`. In addition, when I am running those code, each item in `var items` is displayed twice in the spinner, how can I stop that ? And (`button4`) if the user has input the same value two times, I want to display a `toast message` saying that you have already input this value.

EDIT:
The `button5` remove the item from spinner and doesn't delete it permanently, so when I close and reopen the app, the item deleted re-appear in the spinner. Also, each item in `var items` is being displayed twice in the `spinner`, but the new added items are being displayed once.
Please help me solving those problems..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Declare your items list outside the OnCreate method.

```
List<string> items;


protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
    ....

    items = new List<string> (savedItems) {"1", "2", "3"};
    _spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);
    spinner.Adapter = _spinnerAdapter;    

    button5.Click += delegate {
         // To remove the selected item, first remove the selected item from the list, then call NotifyDataSetChanged
         items.remove(spinner.SelectedItem.ToString ());
         _spinnerAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();
    };

}
```

and as for, items is displayed twice in the spinner

```
var savedItems = prefs.GetStringSet (KEY_FOR_TRY, new List<string> ());
var items = new List<string> (savedItems) {"1", "2", "3"};
```

Are you doing this correct? Your list now contains the collection savedItems + {"1", "2", "3"}

Edit:

Sorry, I was wrong. With a spinner 'NotifyDataSetChanged()' seems not to be working. You'll need to set the adapter again.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Spinner mySpinner;
    Button button;

    List<string> items;
    ArrayAdapter<string> _spinnerAdapter;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
        mySpinner = FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.mySpinner);

        items = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };

        _spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);
        mySpinner.Adapter = _spinnerAdapter;

        button.Click += delegate {
            items.Remove (mySpinner.SelectedItem.ToString ());
            mySpinner.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);
        };
    }
}
```

This works. I've tested.

Edit:

Replace

```
 editor.Remove(spinner.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

with:

```
 editor.PutStringSet (KEY_FOR_TRY, items);
 editor.Apply ();
```

You're trying to remove the selected item in the spinner from the SharedPreference, While the selected item is inside a list which is inside SharedPreference.

Comment: Where should I put those 2 line of code to stop displaying the items twice ? And as for deleting item from spinner, I didn't worked.

Comment: i think the collection savedItems already contains {"1", "2", "3"}. var items = new List<string> (savedItems); This will get rid of the duplicates I think

Comment: Okay, that's great but one problem pop up. This is not saving user input anymore. And if I add `(saveditems)` after `items = new List<string>` this will display the items twice but will save the user input. In addition, when removing an item from spinner then reopen the app, the item re-appear. I want the Item to be removed permanently.

Comment: Remove the item from shared preference as well inside the button click

Comment: I thought about that but I don't know why it didn't worked. I am thinking if I can remove duplicate items in `_spinnerAdapter` so that will not display twice the items. How can I do that ?

Comment: This worked but the problem of the items being displayed twice in the spinner continues.

Comment: replace  `items = new List<string> (savedItems) {"1", "2", "3"};` with   `items = new List<string> (savedItems);`

Comment: Well, but now the values (1, 2, 3) are stored as saved items (and not default spinner's items). Cause they aren't declared anymore in my code. Thus, if I run my program on a new device, (1, 2, 3) won't be displayed in the spinner. Isn't it ?